# Playing a video inside a game application

Tags: java, android, video, andengine

Currently I am learning about games in android using andengine, the problem concern playing a video at my game and continue my application. I search about it, most examples propose using VideoView or MediaPlayer:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);     
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://project.game.super"+"/"+R.raw.small);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
}
```

Although I could play the video, the game did not continue at the end of it. Other problem is that I can only play the video at the beginning of the game using the code above. How can I play a video inside my game whenever I want without interrupt it.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you take real world examples, for instance Video Ads, then you see that they use own Activities to show the Videos. This means you could also use an extra Activity, call it "ShowVideoActivity" and let your existing code execute there. After playing go back to your previous calling activity.